# What is the relationship between 2-3-4- Trees and Red-Black Trees

Tags: algorithm

How are these two types of trees equivalent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-3-4_tree) has this to say on the subject.

> 2-3-4 trees are an isometry of red-black trees, meaning that they are
>   equivalent data structures. In other words, for every 2-3-4 tree,
>   there exists at least one red-black tree with data elements in the
>   same order. Moreover, insertion and deletion operations on 2-3-4 trees
>   that cause node expansions, splits and merges are equivalent to the
>   color-flipping and rotations in red-black trees. Introductions to
>   red-black trees usually introduce 2-3-4 trees first, because they are
>   conceptually simpler.

If you would like a more specific answer, you are welcome to ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert 2-3-4 trees to red black tree by introducing a red node for 3 child one and 2 red nodes for 4 child one. The resulting tree will be binary tree. So in this way 2-3-4 tree is kind of equivalent to red black tree.